# Uncertain Set theory: example and axiom clarification

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, computer-science, computational-mathematics, fuzzy-set

I am working through the work of Baoding Liu on uncertainty theory, specifically uncertain sets. The concept was introduced to represent 'unsharp' concepts such as humans being 'tall' or 'young' or a car being 'fast'.

I have two questions in relation to this. I'm posting as one as I believe this is the first post on uncertain set theory.

I believe I understand Axioms One through Three as defined in [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10700-012-9128-7). Particularly, I understand Axiom Three (the Subadditivity Axiom) to be:

> The set function value of a union of sets is always less than or equal to the sum set function values of the individual sets.

However Axiom Four (the Product Axiom) I am unclear on, stated here for clarity:

[image: The Product Axiom]

Problem One: specifically, I am unclear as to (i) whether the product series operation is producing a Cartesian product, or a true value (and if so, how), and (ii) how the intersection operator returns a value after calling the set function on each event.

Problem Two: I am failing to make the connection between the theory and the provided examples, below:

[image: The provided examples]

Some help in deciphering this concept would be much appreciated.

(Far from exhaustive) Readings:

- Main paper, [2012](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10700-012-9128-7)
- Preceding paper, [2010](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Baoding_Liu/publication/228638230_Uncertain_set_theory_and_uncertain_inference_rule_with_application_to_uncertain_control/links/02e7e52836f1584b46000000/Uncertain-set-theory-and-uncertain-inference-rule-with-application-to-uncertain-control.pdf)
- Heavy reading, [2015](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-662-44354-5)

Comment: Andrés, could you please explain why this question does not fit under the "set-theory" tag?

Comment: I believe these two are independent, but I may add the fuzzy set theory tag and see if someone there has any ideas. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: By author's own admission the notion of an uncertain set is different from random sets, (classical) fuzzy sets and (classical) rough sets. To quote him, "Different from random set (..), fuzzy set (..)  and rough set (..), this paper
will introduce a concept of uncertain set..."

Comment: Thought so - thanks for confirming. Nonetheless, someone well versed in fuzzy theory may understand this area better than I.